# Show a WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn's value when loading the DataGrid (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

In my view I use a `DataGrid` to display and edit database entries. Now I need one of the `DataGridTextColumn`s to be replaced by a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. The remaining `DataGridTextColumn`s are filled by an `ObservableCollection` (`CurrentFilters`) but the `CombBox` takes static values from an enumeration turned into a list (`FilternameList`).
I did this so that the user can't just write anything into that specific column and has to use pre-defined values.
The problem now is, that the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` doesn't display any values when (re-)loading the view. There is also an issue - or something I really don't understand - with how the values chosen in a ComboBox stay displayed after choosing them.

Here's the DataGrid:

```XAML
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentFilters, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" UseLayoutRounding="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contraction" Binding="{Binding ChannelId, Converter={cv:IDtoContractionConverter}}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="FilterName" Width="Auto" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ConfigViewModel.FilternameList}}"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding FilterName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FilterCharValue" Binding="{Binding FilterCharValue}" Width="300"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FilterNumberValue" Binding="{Binding FilterNumberValue}" Width="140"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FilterDescription" Binding="{Binding FilterDescription}" Width="Auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is what my current progress looks like:
[image: Current Progress]

The first line is what the `FilterName` column looks like right now, when loading the `DataGrid`.
The second line is what it looks like when selecting a new value from the `ComboBox`. It is also what the default should be when loading the `DataGrid`. The values are there, I just dont know how to display them.
The third line shows the `ComboBox` filled with values of an enumeration that can be selected.

---

**tl;dr**: I need to find a way to show the values from the `ObservableCollection` after changing them at runtime, in a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` when loading/editing the `DataGrid`.

Comment: What type are `FilterName` and `ConfigViewModel.FilternameList`?

Comment: FilterName is a string out of the ObservableCollection CurrentFilters. ConfigViewModel.FilternameList is a static List of an enum.

Comment: I don't see any problems in the XAML. You'll need to post some of the code for the properties and how they're loaded.